# Having trouble printing a singly linked list stack recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, stack, function-definition

I'm currently having trouble figuring out how to do this. My idea right now is to have the stack `pop()` `this` every time `print` is called recursively within itself, but that is not working for me.

```
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::print() const {  
    if (top->next == nullptr) {
        cout << "End of list" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << top->data;
        this->pop();
        print();
    }
}
```

When I declare a Stack of type int in my main via `Stack<int> test`,  I get the error `"passing const Stack<int> as 'this' argument discards qualifiers`.

Comment: You can not output sequentially something that has N elements with O( 1 ) complexity.:)

Comment: Is your question about how to print a linked list in O(1) time complexity, or about the build errors? Please make sure that the title of the question is a short summary of the problem you're asking about. And that you're actually ask a question. Please take some time to refresh [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Oops, I misread the assignment; we're actually supposed to just be printing it recursively, it doesn't actually mention anything about time complexity.

Comment: @Logan87654321 The error message means that some of the used functions top or pop is not a constant function.

Comment: In ordet to be recursive, a function should call itself at some point. Where does your function call itself?

Comment: "discards qualifiers" usually means that you change what is declared as const.  The word "const" means that you promise not to change something.  What do you change in your function which you promised not to change?

Answer (score 1):

> `passing const Stack<int> as 'this' argument discards qualifiers`

This is your problem. You qualified your `print` function with `const`. That is a promise that you will not change the stack as you print it (which is a reasonable expectation). Calling `pop` would change the stack, breaking that promise.

*The "qualifier" in the compiler's error message is `const`, so "discards qualifiers" basically means "discards your promise to not change `*this`".*

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function is not a recursive function (as you showed it before updating your question).

Moreover it has undefined behavior when is called for an empty stack (that is when the pointer `top` is equal to `nullptr`).

As for the error message then the function `pop` changes the stack (it is a non-constant member function) while it is called from the constant function `print`. So the compiler issue an error.

Thus it it is supposed that the function `print` will change the stack during outputting its values then it shall be declared as a non-constant function.

The function can look something like it is shown below. I assume that the function `push` or its analog is declared something like

```
void push( const T & );
```

Here you are.

```
template <class T>
std::ostream & Stack<T>::print( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) 
{
    if ( this->top )
    {
        os << top->data << ' ';

        auto value = top->data;

        this->pop();

        this->print( os );

        this->push( value );      
    }

    return os;
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
Stack<int> test;

//...

test.print() << '\n';
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows the function above with minor changed applied to the standard class template std::stack (because you did not show your stack definition).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

template <class T>
std::ostream & print( std::stack<T> &st, std::ostream &os = std::cout ) 
{
    if ( not st.empty() )
    {
        os << st.top() << ' ';

        auto value = st.top();

        st.pop();

        print( st, os );

        st.push( value );      
    }

    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    std::stack<int> st( std::stack<int>::container_type { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 } );

    print( st ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5
```